# Как получить данные из Json

Tags: java, json, android-studio

Запрос возвращает вот такой вот ответ

```
[
  {
   "id": 567,
    "bank": "2",
    "data": "2019-09-04T00:00:00+00:00",
    "eursell": "10.6000",
    "eurbay": "10.7000",
    "usasell": "9.6500",
    "usabay": "9.7000",
    "rusell": "0.1450",
    "rubay": "0.1464"
   }
]
```

Как можно будет получить эти значения?

Answer (score 0):

Есть библиотеки которые работают с Json форматом. `Gson`, `Jackson`, `json-simple` одни из самых распространённых